# Problems deleting files, with names grep 'ed

Tags: linux, bash

A text file contains a a list of sha5 hashes and the files. Those should be deleted. looking like this:

```
01115896a225d60b6e8b833b10955d2c "./path/to file/file-name"
01115896a225d60b6e8b833b10955d2c "./path/to file/file name"
01159159b1bfaaa35d0055abf185f662 "./path/to file/filename"
```

I extract the file name, matching the sh5 hash with:

```
b=$(grep $sha5key data-file.txt | awk {'first = $1; $1=""; print $0'}|sed 's/^ //g')
```

I now verify, the file exists:

My $b result looking like: `"./path/to file/filename"`  The files/paths are inside ""

```
if test -f "$b"; then
echo $b
rm -f $b
fi
```

The files do exist (can delete them manually, this works), however, they fail to delete inside the script. What is missing or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, the shell doesn't treat quotes in your data (data read from files, in variables, etc) as part of shell syntax, it treats them as just part of the data. Simply put, quotes go *around* data, not *in* data. That means that to get the filename, you're going to have to remove the double-quotes as part of how you parse and process the file.

If the format is sufficiently consistent (i.e. each line consists of a hash, a single space, a double-quote, the filename, then another double-quote), you can extract out the filename with `sed`:

```
b=$(sed -nE "s/^${$sha5key} \"(.*)\"/\\1/p" data-file.txt)
```

How it works: The `-n` option tells `sed` not to print lines from the file unless explicitly told to (which the `p` option on the substitution is going to do). The `-E` option tells it to use extended regular expression syntax, which is a bit cleaner. Then there's an `s` (substitute) command that matches the expected pattern with the right hash, with the parentheses selecting whatever's between the double-quotes; the replacement pattern, `\1` (with the backslash doubled to escape it), replaces the entire line with just what was in the parentheses, i.e. the filename. And the `p` option tells it to print the result; since this happens *only* if the replacement happens, this and the `-n` option means that only the matching line will be printed.

Then you need to put double-quotes around the variable references. Without them, the shell will split the filename, and (for example) try to delete "./path/to" and
"file/file-name" rather than "./path/to file/file-name". It can also get confused by some other characters in the filenames. You should pretty much always [put double-quotes around variable references](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

```
if test -f "$b"; then
    echo "$b"
    rm -f "$b"
fi
```

Note that if more than one line has a matching hash, you'll get a result with multiple filenames separated by newline characters. If this is a possibility, you'll need to parse out the separate filenames from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several matching files, `b` is a single string with all your files. So your test for existence  is looking for a file called `"./path/to file/file-name1"\n"/path/to file/file name2"\n`.

You likely want to put everything in an array and iterate array members.

Comment: They are already quoted inside the file

Comment: Yes, it's quote issue, but somehow different - have to see how fix that

Comment: See my changed answer

Comment: Problem sorted. There were actually 2 Problems for this cause and I did skip to post :(. Somehow the sha5sum was occasionally wrong extracted and therefore could not find a match and second, the quotes around the file names. Fixed: Validating the inner loop sha5sum via if condition and second, not extracting the path and name, but grabbing the 2nd column and the var in quotes